# List Positioning in itextsharp 5

Tags: asp.net, itext, report, pdf-generation

I didn't find a proper way to position things in `itextsharp`.

I want Intended lists:
[image]
But what actually I have is current list:
[image]
If I add another list it appends after the first one but not one the right of current. Is there a way to do this?

```
List li = new List(List.UNORDERED);

li.SetListSymbol("\u2022");      
li.Add("Two");
li.Add("Three");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well No one answered this query. I found the solution.

We can just have a **table** with **1 row and 2 columns**. Each column will have a list inside. So table cells support the alignment of text. If someone still need help. Comment below